# Is it an accepted pattern to use a common junction table for all N:M relations?

Tags: sql, design-patterns, many-to-many

I've seen several databases which implements many-many relations by using a generic *common* junction table. I've never found this pattern in any literature, I suppose it's an anti-pattern, but does it have a name?

The usual approach is of course to use a distinct junction table for EACH many-many relation, not to put all relations in a generic common/global table for all relations in the whole database.

Btw, the reason I think it's an anti-pattern (at least when using RDBMS) is that you cannot have referential integrity on foreign keys.

Comment: it is not an accepted pattern, it's an anti-pattern for sure.

Comment: I don't see it as anti-pattern, especially if you have metadata about that relationship, plus one normally indexes these tables, so joins don't have that much of impact.

Comment: Yes, lack of RI is the big drawback - it really isn't a correct relational model any more.